# how to check if multiple objects are empty in an array

Tags: javascript

I want to check if objects within an array is empty or not.
This is how I receive my data and the object length is dynamic so I cannot use any hard coded condition.

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}] // length is dynamic
```

I have ways liek:

```
 Object.keys(myarray[0]).length === 0; //but this applies only for object.
```

is there an elegant way of checking this in one condition by any chance?

Comment: Do you want to check if at least 1 object in the array is empty or if there are more than one object in the array empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect if there are any empty objects in your array, use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) combined with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

```js
const anyEmptyObjects = myarray.some(o => Object.keys(o).length === 0)
```

---

To retrieve the empty objects, use the same predicate with [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const emptyObjects = myarray.filter(o => Object.keys(o).length === 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)? Though I suppose that's not much different

```
let a = [{},{test:1},{},{},{test:2},{},{},{test:3},{},{}];
let result = a.map((ele) => (Object.entries(ele) == 0));
```

**output**

```
[true, false, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true]
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete @jmp 's solution you can get the final answer of `hasEmapty` like this:

```js
const hasEmpty = arr => arr.reduce((acc, obj)=> acc || !Object.entries(obj).length, false)


//---

let a = [{},{test:1},{},{},{test:2},{},{},{test:3},{},{}];
let b = [{test: 3}, {test: 4}, {test: 5}]
let c = [{},{}]
let d = []

console.log(hasEmpty(a))
console.log(hasEmpty(b))
console.log(hasEmpty(c))
console.log(hasEmpty(d))
```